# how to get scene\root of a component in javafx

Tags: automated-tests, javafx-8, scene

I test my swing\javafx app using automaton.

To test the javafx part i need the scene\root of a certain component.
Is there a generic way to get it? Maybe all the open scenes like JFrame.getFrames()?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear: can't you just call `getScene()` on the component?

Comment: I don't have the component, notice that the swing equivalent i gave is static, and in the automaton it just gives me the component based on a text or type search.

Comment: OK, I was confused by "of a certain component". I don't think there is a (public API) way to do that in JavaFX.